# avoid component re-creation upon immutable data change

Tags: angular, rxjs

I made a plunkr to illustrate the issue (the numbers are very high to illustrate the issue properly, because it's happening with smalles datasets with more data inside each row).

https://plnkr.co/edit/YVaFZ7mACeQErLJuIFpZ?p=preview

With this simple function inside it:

```
populateArray(){
    const newArray = [];
    const start = Date.now();
    for(const i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
      newArray.push({name: 'item ' + i, data: 'data'+i});
    }
    this.array = newArray;
    this.timer = Date.now() - start;
  }
```

When you click on the button, it takes ~35ms to generate the array, and the page freezes for a way larger amount of time, which is logic because you're creating a lot of dom components.

Now the issue is that when you click on it once again, the page freezes again because it will recreate all of the components, since the array is immutable, the one provided is a brand new one.

Because of the immutable nature of data emitted by `Observable`, the immutable state can't be avoided.

That being said, how can one improve performance for this kind of issue? Because in my production case, data changes are not very large, you can assume that 90% of the data returned will be the same, so creating the components again isn't needed for most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should not display/create so many elements. How do your users should see/use all of the 100k elements at once? Think of a better UI, add filters or something.

Another technique to solve this is so-called "virtual scroll" or "windowing". Idea is that you display/calculate only currently visible content. Here are some libraries based on this:

- [angular2-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll)
- [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Grid)

Comment: In my real-world case, I'm using @angular/material to display a list of items, this list can grow to a rough maximum of 1000 items, and having pagination on it would cause UX issues. When I'm updating the list of items, I get a new array and the creation of the new items freezes the page for ~1s, that's a very bad UX issue too :/

Comment: Well, are you sure that this slowdown is caused by the DOM operations? Browser performance and optimisations is a kind of "black box", you can't be sure without actually **measuring**

Comment: I suggest you to use Chrome `Performance` tab for this - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/

Comment: And **only after** you have identified the problem think of a way to fix it